# How can we sort on a few columns of tables in grails?

Tags: javascript, grails

I want to sort the columns on the basis of User ID, First Name, Last Name, Registration Date, Validation date

Here's my gsp code:

```
<table style="width: 100%" id="sorttables">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th onclick="sortTable(0)">User Id</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(1)">First Name</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(3)">Registration Date</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(4)">Validation Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="test">
        <g:each in="${userStats}" var="userStat">
            <tr style="background-color: #efefef; border: solid white;">
                <td>${userStat.id}</td>
                <td><b>${userStat.firstName}</b></td>
                <td><b>${userStat.lastName}</b></td>
                <td><b>${userStat.email}</b></td>
                <td><b>${userStat.phone}</b></td>
                <td><g:formatDate date="${userStat.registrationDate}" type="date" style="MEDIUM"/></td>
                <td><g:formatDate date="${userStat.validationDate}" type="date" style="MEDIUM"/></td>
            </tr>
            <g:each in="${userStat.games}" var="game" >
                <tr  onclick="unfoldStats(${game.id}, ${userStat.id},'${params.startDate}', '${params.endDate}')">
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td colspan="5" style="cursor: pointer">
                        Game: <b>${game.name}</b> (opened: ${game.timeOpened} times. Current High scores: ${game.highestScore}/${game.maxScore}, last played: <g:formatDate date="${game.latestPlayed}" type="date" style="MEDIUM"/>) <g:if test="${game.numberGameEvents > 0}"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></g:if>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr >
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td colspan="5" id="user-game-${game.id}-${userStat.id}">

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </g:each>


        </g:each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here's how the table looks like:

[image]

I tried to sort a few columns using java script in grails. Here's my JS Code:

```
function sortTable(n) {
    var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
    table = document.getElementById("sorttables");
    switching = true;
    // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
    dir = "asc";
    /* Make a loop that will continue until
    no switching has been done: */
    while (switching) {
        // Start by saying: no switching is done:
        switching = false;
        rows = table.rows;
        /* Loop through all table rows (except the
        first, which contains table headers): */
        for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
            // Start by saying there should be no switching:
            shouldSwitch = false;
            /* Get the two elements you want to compare,
            one from current row and one from the next: */
            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
            /* Check if the two rows should switch place,
            based on the direction, asc or desc: */
            if (dir == "asc") {
                if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                    // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            } else if (dir == "desc") {
                if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                    // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
            /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
            and mark that a switch has been done: */
            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
            switching = true;
            // Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
            switchcount ++;
        } else {
            /* If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
            set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again. */
            if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                dir = "desc";
                switching = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But was unsuccessful to do so. This is what the error looks like:

[image]

I want the sorted tables with user data along with their game reports.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a hero in JS, therefore my question would be, why didn't you sort your "userStats" with the default grails-mimik?

Answer (score 0):

I am no DOM or JS expert.  I read your codes.  I think you are using a bubble sort in the client side.  Grails is a MVC project. I think you should sort your records in server side in the controller instead.  I googled some sample. So, you don't have to sort in the client side with so many line of Javascript codes.

```
def index() {
   def myUserAccountlist = YourUserAccountDomain.findAll(sort: ['userId': 'asc','firstName':'asc', 'lastName':'asc', 'registrationDate':'asc', 'validationDate':'asc'])
   respond myUserAccountlist
}
```

findAll() will return all your records for this domain.  And then you type the names of the fields you want in the sort argument.

respond will send this already sorted list to the view.

Save you ton of times to roll your own.

On the other hand, if you must sort in the client side. I don't know how to program it.  I will use the JQuery datatables instead.  It is just couple line of codes to configure the datatables to sort the html table.

I know this is not exactly the answer you want.  But I hope this help.